# PHP: Can I choose the order in which database results are returned

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using using *mysqli_fetch_array()* to pull comments from my database but is there anyway to pull them out in the order of newest first?

Here is my code:

```
while($row_comments = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_comments)){
?>
    <div class="itemFullWidth itemStyle">
        <p><?php echo $row_comments['comment_author'];?> says:
        <br>
        <?php echo $row_comments['comment_content'] ?>
        </p>
    </div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` to your query?

Comment: can you post the sql statement you are sending to the database ?

Comment: @Sam Your question title implies that you are asking about field/column ordering, but your actual question seems to imply that you'd like to order the results/rows returned from the database. Perhaps you could re-word/clarify the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY date DESC`

More about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).

Note that `DESC` (descending) is important here in order to get the newest. The default would be `ASC` (ascending).

The `ORDER BY` only functions correctly in case your date is correctly stored, not as a `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of *fields*

```
SELECT field1, field5, fieldXX, field_last FROM ...
   //  ^ here your order goes
```

But if you want to order returned *rows*,

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY id DESC
// DESC means biggest value first ^
```

Comment: He wants the order or rows, not columns (he asks for newest first).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using *mysqli_fetch_array* to pull comments, you are using it to put the results into an array. You are likely using *mysqli_query* to fetch the comments, so you need to be looking there, not in your array function that merely formats the already fetched and sorted results...

Something like:

```
"SELECT fields,go,here FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC
```

will work, if you're using an ID, or you can sort them by *comment_date* for example, if you have such a field, etc.